# How to exclude node_modules folder from TFS Fortify build?

Tags: tfs, node-modules, fortify

I am running a TFS build for Fortify security results. The web app has a npm/gulp task dependency so those tasks run correctly which then creates the node_modules folder. I then push the scan results to Fortify which is flagging over 600 issues within the node_modules folder. Is there a task I can add to the TFS-Fortify build to run the gulp/npm tasks and then remove or exclude the node_modules from the Fortify scan results?

I have tried adding a windows batch task to the build with the path set to where the node_modules folder will be added and set the arguments to `rmdir "node_modules"` which causes `##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.` Any suggestions?

Comment: Fortify supports excluding files and/or folders from the scan in the translation phase. How are you executing the scan, by sending the scan job to the server or running the scan locally on the build server?

Comment: We are sending the scan from TFS to the Fortify server where it then scans on results from TFS's build.